# How to use Telerik ORM Reverse Mapping woth SQL Compact 4.0?

Tags: telerik, mapping, sql-server-ce, reverse, telerik-open-access

I was using Telerik ORM in Reverse Mapping Mode using SQL Server Compact 3.5. I upgraded the database to SQL Compact 4.0 and the reverse mapping started giving errors.

So i tried to recreate Reverse Mapping Model using Telerik ORM wizard and its says "Invalid database type".

I have the latest version of Telerik ORM
I have Visual Studio 2010 SP1 installed
I have Visual Studio Tools for SQL Compact 4.0 SP1 Installed.
I have all the necessary components installed for creating and managing SQL Compact 4.0
Telerik ORM created in a standard way works fine with SQL Comapct 4.0 but when i try to create model from SQL Compact 4.0 database using Reverse Mapping Wizard, it gives errors.

Has anyone experienced this issue?
Can anyone confirm that Reverse Mapping is supported with SQL Compact 4.0 or not?

An expert's response is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create your data layer using the [Classic API approach](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/development-environment-wizards-reverse-main-window.html).

You could use the [new approach](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/openaccess-tasks-update-schema-mechanisms-update-db-from-model.html) for generating a domain model in your application, where the problem does not arise and SQL CE 4.0 can be used.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am aware of both approaches and have used both in different apps. However, i was wondering what happens to my existing code base which uses Reverse Mapping and when i upgrade my SQL CE 4.0 and Change Reverse Mapping to the "DB First" New approach whose link you mentioned.? Will my existing code remain functional without any changes? Do i need to make a lot of changes so that i could be able to use the new approach? Responses & solution/suggestion will be help. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually you could use the Convert to Domain Model wizard (http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/getting-started-root-migration-tool-overview.html) in order to convert your Classic API model. Your reversed mapped model will be converted and replaced with a new domain model. No other modifications in your application are needed.